# Missing files on libopencv-contrib?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, opencv

I'm trying to use some features/modules of the *opencv_contrib* [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libopencv-contrib-dev), but apparently the version on Ubuntu's repositories (using 18.04 LTS), for some reason, does not include the tracking module?

I've checked against the source code on their [git repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) and verified that the tracking module is indeed part of the 3.2 release, but I still do not find the code anywhere on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick [search for `tracking.hpp`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=opencv2%2Ftracking.hpp) shows that only upcoming 20.04 LTS will have this feature out-the-box.

But for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can use thirdparty PPA [`ppa:alfonsosanchezbeato/opencv-tracking`](https://launchpad.net/~alfonsosanchezbeato/+archive/ubuntu/opencv-tracking) with this feature.
Install packages from it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alfonsosanchezbeato/opencv-tracking
sudo apt-get install libopencv-contrib-dev
```

and you will get needed `tracking.hpp`:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S opencv2/tracking.hpp
> libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64: /usr/include/opencv2/tracking.hpp
> ```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for, it beats having to compile it manually.